# Why doesn't Carp verbose produce a stack trace?

Tags: perl, exception, stack-trace, die

Why doesn't `use Carp qw(verbose);` make `die` produce a stack trace? I mean that just

> ERROR at ./test.pl line 8.

is printed, but I want also a stack trace.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Carp qw(verbose);

sub c { die "ERROR"; }

sub b {
  c;
}

sub a {
  b;
}

a;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of `use Carp qw( verbose );`, the documentation says:

> As a debugging aid, you can force Carp to treat a `croak` as a `confess` and a `carp` as a `cluck` across all modules.

You don't use `croak` or `carp`, so `use Carp qw( verbose );` is useless.

You can achieve what you want by overriding `die` or by creating a `$SIG{__DIE__}` handler. [Carp::Always](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Carp%3a%3aAlways) is a pre-made solution that does this for you.

Answer (score 5):

Try using [Devel::Confess](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel%3a%3aConfess). Usage:

```
perl -d:Confess myscript.pl
```

It makes `die` print a stack track.

Comment: And so does Carp::Always

Comment: Yep. The advantage of Devel::Confess is that it even adds stack traces to blessed exception objects. Carp::Always doesn't; it should be called Carp::NearlyAlways. :-)

Comment: ow, so you're saying Devel::Confess breaks code that throws objects?

Comment: Nope - it's cleverer than that. It subclasses whatever class the object was blessed into, adding a stack trace, reblesses the exception into the new subclass, and rethrows it.

Answer (score 3):

Then you want [`confess`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Carp.html)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Carp qw(confess);

sub c { confess "ERROR"; }
sub b { c; }
sub a { b; }
a();
```

Outputs:

```
ERROR at confess.pl line 6.
        main::c() called at confess.pl line 7
        main::b() called at confess.pl line 8
        main::a() called at confess.pl line 9
```

And if you can't change your other code, you can use a `$SIG{__DIE__}`

```
use Carp qw(confess);

$SIG{__DIE__} = \&confess;

sub c { die "ERROR"; }
sub b { c; }
sub a { b; }
a();
```

Comment: No, it does not address my issue. I want `die` in a third-party module to print a stack trace WITHOUT modifying that module (that is it is not acceptable to replace `die` with `croak` or `confess` or whatever in that module, I can't modify the module)

Comment: It is not a fact of acceptable or not. `Carp` will not do what you want. `Carp` works as described in the documentation. So the answer is correct. Your code does not work because this is not how `Carp` was designed.

Comment: `use Carp qw(croak)` does not normally print a stack trace. It will normally only mention one line where the error occurred. `use Carp qw(confess)` can be used to get a stack trace, and `croak` can be made to act like `confess` using `use Carp qw(croak verbose)`. The reason you get a stack trace from `croak` in your example is that `croak` normally uses package boundaries to determine which line number to report the error at; however in your example the entire stack is in the same package (`main`), so it cannot determine which line number to report the error at, so prints the entire stack.